# $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ and $F^{m,n}$ are isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra

I am going through the proof of theorem 3.60 in Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, 3rd ed., which states the following:

> Suppose $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is a basis of $V$ and $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ is a basis of $W$/ Then, $\mathcal{M}$ is an isomorphism between $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$ and $\mathbf{F}^{m,n}$

Proof:

It is easy to show that $\mathcal{M}(S + T) = \mathcal{M}(S) + \mathcal{M}(T)$, and $\mathcal{M}(\lambda S) = \lambda\mathcal{M}( S)$, for $S,T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ and $\lambda \in \mathbf{F}$. It follows that $\mathcal{M}$ is linear.

It remains to show that $\mathcal{M}$ is injective and surjective. We begin by proving injectivity. Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$, and $\mathcal{M}(T) = 0$. It follows from the definition of a matrix that $Tv_k = 0\; \text{for}\; k = 1, \ldots, n$. Since $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is a basis of $V$, this implies that $T = 0$, and therefore $\mathcal{M}$ is injective.***

We now show that $\mathcal{M}$ is surjective. Suppose $A \in \mathbf{F}^{m,n}$ and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ such that

\begin{equation*}
Tv_k = \sum_{j = 1}^{m} A_{j,k} w_j,\; \text{for}\; k= 1, \ldots, n
\end{equation*}

It follows from the definition of a matrix that $\mathcal{M}(T) = A$, and therefore the $range\; \mathcal{M} = \mathbf{F}^{m,n}$

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Question:

My point of of contention lies in the proof of injectivity above. In particular, the last statement (denoted by ***) feels like a logical leap. How does $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ being a basis of $V$ have any bearing on $T$ being the zero map?.

Comment: What does it mean for a setto be linearly independent?

Comment: @rubikscube09 a list $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is linearly independent if the only choice of coefficients that makes $a_1v_1 + \ldots + a_nv_n = 0$ is $a_1 = \ldots = a_n = 0$. But in the above case, the zero map is the map such that $Tv = 0, \forall v \in V$, right? Meaning, the linear independence of $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is irrelevant, no?

Comment: Earlier on in the book under "Linear Maps and Basis of Domain", Axler states that every linear map is uniquely determined by how it acts on the basis of the domain. Since v1,…,vn is a basis and the linear map T maps each of these to 0, the linear map T must be the zero map as the zero map also maps the basis vectors to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Any vector $v\in V$ can be written as $v=c_1v_1+\ldots c_nv_n$. So $Tv=0$ for all $v\in V$. Hence $T$ is the zero map.

Answer (score 0):

Since $Tv_k=0$ for $k=1, \dots, n$, then for all $v\in V$
\begin{align*}
Tv&=T(a_1v_1+\cdots+a_kv_k) &\text{since $v_1, \dots, v_n$ is a basis}\\
&=a_1T(v_1)+\cdots+a_kT(v_k) &\text{since $T$ is a linear map}\\&=a_1\cdot 0+\cdots+a_k\cdot 0 =0
\end{align*}